# Call javascript without function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I need to create a script called `footer.js` to validate the form below. I cannot make any modifications in the `index.html` file.

I need to validate that the `name` field to be 3 characters with a space, and the `age` field to be a number between 1 and 110. All fields need to be required.

How do I do this? How do I call my `footer.js` file? There isn't even an `onsubmit` function, just the `<form action="#">`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/footer.js"></script>

<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact</legend>
        <div class="textinput">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>

        <div class="textinput">
            <label for="name">Age</label>
            <input type="text" name="age>
        </div>

        <div class="radioSelection">
            <label>Select one</label>            
            <input type="radio" name="favorit" id="html" value="html">
            <label for="html">HTML</label>
            <input type="radio" name="favorit" id="js" value="js">
            <label for="js">JavaScript</label>
            <input type="radio" name="favorit" id="css" value="css">
            <label for="css">CSS</label>
        </div>

        <div class="textareainput">
            <label for="info">About you:</label>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="action">
            <button>Send</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Look up unobtrusive jquery. You have all the tools in the js file. Start with `$(function() { $("form").on("submit",function() { ... }); })`

Comment: You can use javascript to modify the html elements instead of modifying them through the index.html file directly.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Converting comment to answer</sub>

Look up unobtrusive jquery. You have all the means in the js file.

Start with

```
$(function() { 
  $("form").on("submit",function() { 
   // validations here
  }); 
});
```

If you do NOT want to submit the form, then you need to stop the submission

```
$(function() { 
  $("form").on("submit",function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // cancels the form submit 
   // validations here
  }); 
});
```

Alternative to jQuery is plain JS - this still lives happily in footer.js and is executed when the page has loaded

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].onsubmit=function() {
  // validation here
  return false; // cancels the form submission
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so you are not writing the JavaScript events in the HTML file, it's better to have a JS file handle those events. Which is the purpose of your project. Your file is running you just need to add an event handler for submission. The file would have this structure:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Wait for the DOM to load
    $("form").submit(function(e){ // When a form is submitted
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent normal submit
        /* Validation Here */
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In your footer.js file you can look for the form element and have it run a function by attaching it to the onsubmit event.

You can do this by searching for the form element from the document object model (DOM). Google

> find an element using javascript

and that should point you in the right direction.

I see the code snippet you posted is using `jquery`, which makes what I described above even easier. For this I would google

> jquery find form element

to get the correct syntax.